# Can an SVN repository be cloned when there are branches in the history with invalid names?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have an SVN repository that I would like to clone using git-svn, but in the murky past of this SVN repo there were some branches made with spaces in the name...

When I try to clone, git-svn fails with invalid object name on the revision with said branches.

Is there a way to get around this problem, that doesn't involve starting the clone after the failing revision?

Answer (score 0):

There's a nasty long winded way to fix the problem at source, using the SVN admin tools. You'll need local access to (a copy of) the repository, I think:

1. Dump the SVN repo to text files.
2. Edit the branch names manually (write a script?)
3. Rebuild the SVN repo with the new names.

You might like to consider patching git-svn though. That sounds less painful. Don't forget to post your patch back to upstream for the rest of us to benefit from. :)

P.s. I deliberately haven't posted any command lines to do that because I've never tried, and couldn't promise it'd be right. The tool you're looking for is `svnadmin`.